# Soap UI Pro XML DataSource: error Invalid character entity reference: &#x8 ;

Tags: xml, rest, xpath, soapui

Converting an XML response from an API stopped working in my SOAP UI Pro XML DataSource Step.

The error is:

```
error Invalid character entity reference: &#x8;
```

The XML response is a list of patients.  If I alter the API call so only the first few patients are returned then I don't get the error when converting the XML to properties.

I write this to return the first patient and it works.

```
//PatientInfo[1]/Patient[1]
```

If I call the full list of patients which is 18,000 patients and try to access the first patient using the same XPATH I get the error even if I try to only access the first patient using the same xpath:

```
//PatientInfo[1]/Patient[1]
```

In the XML response 3 patients have this in the first name field:

```
<PatientFirstName>&#x8;Charlie Q.</PatientFirstName>
```

And, I just found out that If I delete the &#x8 ; from the three patients, SOAP UI Pro does not throw the error message.

Can anyone suggest a way to get past this error so I can test the valid patients?

Comment: use a simple search and replace to get rid of the dodgy characters?

Comment: @i alarmed alien would you know how to do that in Soap UI pro after a REST request?  I'd like to set up something automatic because I make the same REST call about 80 times (once for each location).

Comment: @MattJoe Use a custom event handler: http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/custom-event-handlers.html